# IntelliJ JDK 16 Early Access - Any Success? tools.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-16

Has anyone had any success using JDK 16 (https://jdk.java.net/16/) early access build with IntelliJ?

I am able to use JDK 15 early access builds, but when I try JDK 16 I get an error message:

```
Error: Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for 16 (path/to/jdk-16)
```

All of the research I've done says JDK stores tools.jar inside of the path/to/jdk-16/lib folder. Thing is, tools.jar isn't there in the JDK 15 package either, yet JDK 15 works fine.

If anyone has any clue on how to fix this issue I'd appreciate it. I'm still trying, and if I figure it out I'll update this post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `tools.jar` since JDK 9. So when IntelliJ works with JDK 15, it must be aware of this. Then, failing with JDK 16 indicates that this is another case of stup… ahem, broken version comparison.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was an issue: [IDEA-243962](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243962). It is fixed now in 2020.2 version. EAP version is already available [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/).

Answer (score 0):

How to Solve IntelliJ IDEA Error: Cannot determine path to ‘tools.jar‘ library for 17 (C:\Program Files\Java\jd…
**open file**

[image]

**improve the version of IntelliJ idea.**
[image]

update ide then try rerun

source for details:
[enter link description here](https://programmerah.com/how-to-solve-intellij-idea-error-cannot-determine-path-to-tools-jar-library-for-17-cprogram-filesjavajd-38877/)

Answer (score -3):

I downgraded my Java from 15 to 11. Now it is working fine.
(IntelliJ Idea 2020.1)